# Vasicek process with no reversion

Tags: vasicek

I want to prove that as the speed of reversion $\lambda$ in the Vasicek process $dR=\lambda(R_{\infty}−R)dt + \sigma d\beta$ approaches 0, the expected long rate
$$r(0,T)=R_{\infty}+\frac{(R(0)-R_{\infty})(1-e^{-\lambda T})}{\lambda T}-
\frac{\sigma^2}{4T\lambda^3}\bigl(2\lambda T+4e^{-\lambda T}-e^{-2\lambda T}-3\bigr)$$
becomes a function of $T$ that will go infinitely negative as $T\rightarrow0$. In other words if there is no tension in the spring pulling it back to a long-term average, an impossible situation
will result. It seems to me that the limit of $\lambda\rightarrow0$ is the zero over zero type. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide a formal definition of your long rate? It should be based on something people are familiar with, such as the instantaneous forward rates $f(t,T)\,.$

Comment: I figured it out! I apply the L'Hospital rule and this becomes a calculus problem! Thanks though!

Comment: By formula (12) in [this paper](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/HOA/JAMDS/8/11.pdf) the formal definition I was asking for is $r(0,T)=-\frac{\log B(0,T)}{T}\,.$ In other words, the "long rate" $r(0,T)$ is the continuously compounded yield of the zero coupon bond $B(0,T)\,.$ I doubt that this becomes infinitely negative as $T$ goes to zero. It is rather the case that $\lim_{T\to 0}r(0,T)=0\,.$